# Integration Test not being fired

Tags: grails

I have the following code

```
class LoginControllerIntegrationTests extends GroovyTestCase {



  def springSecurityService


    @Test
    void testLogin() {


        def dc = new LoginController()
        def loggedInUser =new SentryUser(username: "test@test.com",password: 'password',
                enabled: true).save(failOnError: true)
        dc.springSecurityService = [
                encodePassword: 'password',
                reauthenticate: { String u -> true},
                loggedIn: true,
                getCurrenUser: { loggedInUser }]
        assertTrue springSecurityService.isLoggedIn()


    }




}
```

when I run the command `grails test-app integration:integration` I do see that the files are being compiled and the bootstrap code being executed and seeing the message Tests PASSED. When I look the the reports I see empty html files. Does anybody know what's going on ? I'm using grails 2.1.1

Comment: What happens if you just type: `grails test-app integration:`

Comment: The behavior is exactly the same. I intially was using that then used integration:integration

Comment: What happens if you just type: `grails test-app`

Comment: runs all the tests. I do see results from unit tests only.

Comment: Are your integration tests in the test/integration/ directory?

Comment: Probably unrelated, but GroovyTestCase is a JUnit3-style test so `@Test` isn't needed - methods that are void, start with "test" and have no args (like yours) are considered test methods.

Comment: Thanks for the info. @Burt - I had tried with and without the Test annotation and nothing happened, so the Test which you see was may be from the last version of the file. I don't know what the cause was, but I deleted all the files under the test integration directory and re-created the tests again using create-integration-test and it worked. Thanks for all your help

Answer (score 0):

Re-created the tests using create-integration-test did the trick.